# Null is type object, so it's truthy? What's going on behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, c++, types, programming-languages, type-conversion

I'm reading in my book, "Elegant JavaScript", that `null == true` evaluates as false.  Using an interpreter, I have confirmed this to be `TRUE`.  However, later in the chapter--in fact, on the same page--, it says that when null is given as the condition of an if, while, or for statement, it will be converted to a Boolean and return false.

Can anybody with a deeper insight tell me why this is?  I know where to find browser source code, but I'm not sure how to target the programming that is responsible for this peculiar and unintuive behavior.  Because I know very little C++, I would also appreciate any tips on finding info like this, independently.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I communicated the information incorrectly.  The quote is: "objects are truthy, and null is type object".  I read, 'if an objects primitive value is falsy, the object is still truthy'.  Null is falsy, though, by popular vote, it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An important distinction to make is that the `Type` of `null` is [`Null`](http://es5.github.com/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email#x8.2).

(ignore `typeof` it returns `"object"` for `null` because of bad design and backwards compatibility)

> 11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm # Ⓣ  The comparison
>   x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a
>   comparison is performed as follows:
>
> [... stripped]
>
> 10. Return false.

[The ES5 specification](http://es5.github.com/?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email#x11.9.1)

Says that the comparison with `null` and a `Boolean` should return false because the `Type` of `Null` and `Boolean` are not the same, and none of the other steps in 11.9.3 apply so the default action of `return false` happens

The only case where the `Type` of `x` and `y` are different and either `x` or `y` is `null` but the `==` operation still returns `true` are

> If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
>
> If x is undefined and y is null, return true.

That means `undefined == null` returns `true`

**Of special note:**

There is an [ES6:harmony proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null) to fix `typeof null`

Comment: I don't imagine they spell out the reason for making decisions like this, or reference the code that makes it so

Comment: There is "no code that makes it so". EcmaScript is a specification, you can dig through v8 or spidermonkey if you want to read an implementation of EcmaScript. You should also know that javascript was designed in two weeks in 1995. A lot of bugs were made, they cannot be fixed because it would "break the internet", i.e. backwards compatibility

Comment: This is far from the worst thing in javascript :) my personal most loathed mistake is the value of "this" in a private function. The reason is that javascript was basically developed in its entirety in a very short period of time by one person. Considering that, it's actually a pretty remarkable piece of work, but far from perfectly sensible in every aspect.

Comment: @jamietre There is nothing wrong with the _default value_ of `this` in a _function_. There simply is not notion of "private function".

Comment: A function defined within another function is certainly private, it is not directly accessible to anything outside the outer function. It's just as private as any other variable defined in the function. The default value of "this" is not defined (or `window`). I think it would make a lot more sense that it be defined as the same as the outer value of this.

Comment: Surely there's some source code?  It's nice to know how quickly it was developed because learning it is taking much longer.

Comment: "A local function declaration inside a function should not be treated differently then a global function declaration." It wouldn't be. "This" by default refers to the object which a function belongs to. A global function belongs to `window`. A local function belongs to another function. It's just as consistent (and far more useful, since there's really no practical use for an undefined `this` in a local function) to say that the default value of `this` is the parent object. I understand that one can explain this behaviour in terms of a consistent rule, but that doesn't mean it's a good rule.

Comment: Source code is implementation specific. You can go read the [v8 source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=toboolean+package:http://v8%5C.googlecode%5C.com) but that's v8 specific, there are many javascript engines, knowing about one will help but you should look at what the es5 spec says

Comment: Hey, this actually makes sense, now, but I had to read into the 11.9.3 a little.  Thank you, and everyone else.

Comment: @jamietre `var o = {}; o.f = p.g; o.f();` should `this` be `o` or `p`. It would be really frustrating if you ask me. I agree `this` is a mess but your not proposing an improvement

Comment: It should be `p`. `g` is a member of `p`. Why would assigning a reference to some child object change its natural parent? Anyway, it already works that way if the function is public, e.g. a member of an object: http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/wbPvz/1/ so I think it's reasonable it should work the same way for a private function.

Comment: I think I forgot to hit update: http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/wbPvz/3/ .. the point is, `this` refers to the parent object unless otherwise defined *except* when the function is inside another function. That is inconsistent.

Comment: Wow!  A real magic fight right on my own question. :D  Will the door close or open?

Comment: @jamietre this is just a tangent to the current question, [this can be taken to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript). Also [counter fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbPvz/4/). As a side-note the [JavaScript Garden explain `this`](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this) quite nicely, it works completely differently based on function execution or method execution

Comment: @jamietre *"This" by default refers to the object which a function belongs to.*  That is **not correct**.  The value of `this` is **solely** determined by the way the function is invoked, and that determination is made on every invocation.

Comment: @Pointy with the exception of `.bind`

Comment: Well, ".bind()" returns another function that "fixes" `this` on a particular value, so I *guess* you could say that about "modern" built-in implementations of ".bind()".  Fair enough.

Comment: @Pointy: okay we are getting mired in terminology here. When you assign a function to an object, it obtains a binding context of the owner object. That is a "default": something that happens when you do not explicitly ask for it. It will always be that unless redefined by another action, such as assigning to another object, or invoking with another context. When you create a function in another function, there is no binding context, e.g. no default.

Comment: @jamietre that's not _how it works_. The `this` context is injected into that _function_ when you invoke it as a property of the object. The "binding context" is set on invocation not on assignment

Comment: Anyway, you can keep picking at minutae of how I'm describing the behavor. It's not relevenat. Even Brandan Eich agrees with me. http://brendaneich.com/2011/01/harmony-of-my-dreams/ see 
"lexical this"

Comment: If you guys want to keep discussing this, please take it to chat.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think he refers to the fact that `typeof null == 'object'`, which is unfortunately the case. But that's a peculiarity of the typeof operator, not of null itself. Null is falsy value, but typeof returns "object" for it, according to the spec: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.3

Answer (score 1):

When you compare `null` to `true`, <strike>it's evaluated as `false`,</strike> so it's not equal to `true`. Similarly, when used in any other context where it must be treated as a boolean — like an `if` or `while` expression — it's `false`.

It's not really correct to say that "null is type object", because it is not.  It is `null`. <strike>It doesn't really have any type,</strike> (Thanks @Roee Gavirel) It's got it's own type (the null type) because it isn't anything. In other words, if a variable has the value `null`, that means that it is referring to nothing; no object at all.

*edit* — crap hold on a sec because my brain's still asleep.

OK here's what's in the spec.  If one of the operands of `==` is boolean, then the boolean is  converted to a number (yes really) and the conversion proceeds that way. That's why `null` is `==` to neither `true` nor `false`.  The "strangeness", therefore, is not so much about `null` as it is about the complicated rules for evaluating `==` comparisons.

Section 11.9.3 of the ECMA-262 standard spells it all out in a more-or-less understandable way.  Suffice to say that the semantics of `==` are not at all simple.

Comment: Not true, NULL is a type that can accept only one value (the null). Also it have a auto-casting to bool (when needed) and return a false.

Comment: I gathered the info that "null" was type object from a friend, so it's unreliable, which is why I posed that as a question. :)  I'm not sure if this is an efficient way to check, but `typeof(null)` returns `object` in my interpreter.

Comment: @Pointy the 11.9.3 at the bottom says "if none of the above apply return false" which is what happens

Comment: @Roee, May I ask you to join me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634584/whats-an-auto-casting-bool ?  I already checked google, of course.

Comment: Here's a link to the document: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf.  Cool webpage.

Comment: @Raynos ah so you're saying that *after* converting the boolean to a number and starting the "abstract comparison algorithm" over, it then falls out to the final "return `false`" step?  I guess that may be true if "Type(null)" is the null type and not "Object" (and I *think* that's the case).

Comment: @Pointy that is the case. `Type(null)` is the Null object. The fact the `typeof` operator returns `"object"` is a bug (also murderous rage)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the problem...
if (null == true) = false then (null == false) = true.

if "why" is the question, then the answer is ease of use. (probably taken from C) but if you wish to know if a reference is valid or not you can just do:

```
if (RefValue) {
    //bla bla bla
}
```

Rather then:

```
if (RefValue == null) {
    //bla bla bla
}
```

Comment: `if (something)` tests truthiness. `if (a==b)` attempts to cast two items to the same type and compare them, which only works for things that exist. (e.g `undefined==false` is also false). if you need to compare explicitly to an object you can use `!!` to convert it to true/false, e.g. `!!null==false`

Comment: @jamietre That should work better in the interpreters.  I've been having trouble figuring out how to go about testing via if statements.  Glad to know this new trick.  I wish it were in my book!