# What's an "auto-casting bool"?

Tags: javascript, c++, webkit, boolean, boolean-logic

On the following [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634343/null-is-type-object-so-its-truthy-whats-going-on-behind-the-scenes/7634374#7634374) someone mentioned an "auto-casting bool"

I guess null has an auto-casting bool that is false.  What is it, and what does the code that makes it look like?

Comment: In which language, JavaScript or C? C has no concept of "auto-casting", but it has some implicit conversions.

Comment: Where did you see the term "auto-casting bool" used?  A link would be helpful.

Comment: .. and there is even no boolean type in C.

Comment: [off hand comment stating "auto-casting bool"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634343/null-is-type-object-so-its-truthy-whats-going-on-behind-the-scenes/7634374#7634374)

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  I'm trying to find an example of auto-casting bool code, which I thought would be written in C.

Comment: @alk: C has had a boolean type for more than a decade.

Comment: you are right, I got stuck with c90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "auto-casting bool" is a poor phrase someone used off hand. I believe what they mean is the internal [`ToBoolean`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) operation

Of special note is the [if statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.5) which calls `ToBoolean` on the expression.

I don't know my way around the v8 source code but here is a [search for `ToBoolean` on the v8 repo](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=toboolean+package%3ahttp://v8%5C.googlecode%5C.com).

For reference v8 is the javascript implementation used by chrome and written in C++

Comment: Cool.  I have to update the tags on the other question, too.  Thanks.